# Organizational identity management with Auth0

Tags: auth0

We are building a web application where we need users to create organizations and then manage users within that organization so that their will be organizational identity management and within each organization hierarchy their will be user identity management.

Is it possible to create that level of organizational identity management using Auth0 or any other alternative opensource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends exactly what you want to do, but this should be able to be accomplished using RBAC:

https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/rbac

The Authorization Extension allows you to create groups and give those groups specific permissions based on their roles. You should be able to divide those users into groups and control their permissions that way. You can create admin and let them have specific permissions as well.

https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension/v2

This is a great example of what that looks like:

https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension/v2/implementation/setup